# How to Hide a ID that incrments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

So I'm trying to hide a ID tag that increments depending on how many input fields there are.

I included the HTML at the bottom for the input forms

The numbers at the end of deviceTemplate_(incremented numbers)

ex. deviceTemplate_1 is input field 1

    deviceTemplate_2 is input field 2

```
$(function () {

        // Other Code

        // Trying to use this to hide fields
            var fieldlistSelect = '#deviceTemplate_' + pliPosition;

        //var $loader = $('section[role="main"]');
            var $loader = form.parent();
        //if this exists, then it will execute the following. It will check the whole HTML page.
            $loader && $loader.showLoading();

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: form.attr('action'),
               data: form.serialize(), 
               dataType: 'html'
             }).done(function(html) {

                 $loader && $loader.hideLoading();
                 $(fieldlistSelect).html(html); 
                 $loader && $loader.hideLoading();
                 $(fieldlistSelect).html(html); 

           //Code I'm trying to get to work, not nessecary to use I'm just stuck
                 $('.vinCartApplyButton').click(function(ev) {
                    var aim = $(this);
                    var ap = aim.parent();
                    var newbk = ap.clone(true);
                    var apindex = $('[id^=deviceTemplate_]').index(ap);
                    var bkId = 'deviceTemplate_' + (apindex + 1);
                    newbk.addId('deviceTemplate_' + (apindex + 2));
                    ap.after(newbk);
                });

                //alert(html);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
                //if this exists, then it will execute the following
                $loader && $loader.hideLoading();
                var html = jqXHR.responseText;
            //alert(html);
            });

        });

    });
```

```
<div class="vinCartFormStyling">
<form action="DeviceProcessing-AjaxValidate" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" id="deviceform1">
<fieldset id="deviceTemplate_1"><div class="vinBox">
<BR><div class="vinText"></div>
<BR><input type="text" onblur="convertCase(this)" name="DeviceId" maxlength="17" size="20" 
value="" class="inputfield_en" /> 
</div>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="device_form vinCartApplyButton" value="Apply">
<input type="hidden" name="Platform" value="ALP-HDD">
<input type="hidden" name="SKU" value="xxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="Position" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="PLIUUID" value="abcd1234" id="PLIUUID">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to hide an element that you don't know the `id` for?

Comment: Trying to hide this ID deviceTemplate_#, the problem is at the end of said ID there is a number. So I need to figure out how to hide the ID once it has been incremented